# Network disabled in Windows 8 PC on startup

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, lan, network-adapter

Windows 8 64-Bit pc will not detect network on startup. Every time we have to do a "scan for hardware changes" in device manager. Otherwise it will not connect to network automatically. We did re-installed network driver, updated and checked same network with other PCs. But in other than windows 8, same network works fine. Only 64-bit Windows 8 is having this problem.
We are using Intel DH61WWB3 Mother board with i5 processor.

Comment: Is this a new PC or just a new Win8 install? If the latter, was it fine with the previous OS?

Comment: No. This is old pc and before installing windows 8, it was working fine with XP. We are facing same problem for 4-5 PCs and all are upgraded to windows 8 from XP

Comment: Does the network become visible if you wait 10 mins?

Comment: no. we have to manually enable it after logging in